# How to create autocompletion dropdown with bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

For an input field I need to create a dropdown that will be filled with autocompletion suggestions for user input and displayed by AJAX `.onkeyup` function.

Although there's a very clear documentation about creating dropdowns for buttons, Bootstrap does not provide explanation how to implement the functionality that I'm asking about.

If I implement it this way I can use AJAX calls as I meant to but the dropdown is displayed right after I click on input field and I don't want it to be visible unless it's filled with autocompletion value(s).

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <input class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="search" id="dropdownSearch" placeholder="Search something...">
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownSearch">
    <li>...</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look for [jquery.bootcomplete.js](http://getwebhelp.com/bootcomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery chosen. Click link below for more info.

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/